# Creating a "walled garden" of comments

Tags: comments, buddypress

I'm using Buddypress to create classrooms, where only members of a given class can see and respond to their classmates' comments. I achieved this by filtering `pre_get_comments`, querying for the `user_id`s of the class members.

However, instructors may be members of more than one class, so I needed to also filter out their replies to comments of students who aren't in the logged-in student's class.

I came up with the following solution:

```
function filter_the_comments( $array ) { 

    $comment_IDs = array();

    foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {

        array_push($comment_IDs, $val->comment_ID);

    }    

    foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {

        if ( !in_array( $val->comment_parent, $comment_IDs ) && $val->comment_parent != 0 )
        unset( $array[ $key ] );

    }    

    return $array; 
}; 

add_filter( 'the_comments', 'filter_the_comments', 10, 1 );
```

It works, but as someone who is more a cobbler than a coder, I worry that this may be inefficient, and I'm wondering if there is a better way of achieving the same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions, added as comments:

```
function filter_the_comments( $array ) { 

  $comment_IDs = array();

  foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
    //assuming the comments are sorted by date in ascending order, a parent has to come before the child comment, so there is no need to wait till all subsequent IDs have been added in order to check for this comment's parent
    //the && operator stops executing as soon as a condition fails, so it's more efficient to check if there is a parent first
    //0 evaluates to false and other values to true, so the comparison can be skipped
    if ($val->comment_parent && !in_array( $val->comment_parent, $comment_IDs )) unset( $array[ $key ] );

    //there is no need to add this comment's ID if you have removed it, so put this in the else statement
    else array_push($comment_IDs, $val->comment_ID);

  }    

  return $array; 
};
```